# How do I increment and decrement a field and limit it once for users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hello people I am developing an app, where I have a book table that has two columns  ‘foo’ and ‘bar’ both are integer.

Now I have set the default values to zero. I want a user to be able to click a button and increment them by one and next time the same user clicks on it, the fields would decrement by one. Which means a particular user can only increment it just once and decrement once. The cycle continues: such that a total of ‘foo’ and ‘bar’ could be calculated for all the users
Below is what I have tried:
In the Book’s controller I have

```
Def increase_and_decrease_foo
If @book.foo == 0
@book.foo +=1
@book.save
Else
@book.foo -=1
@book.save
End

Def increase_or_decrease_bar
If @book.bar == 0
@book.bar +=1
@book.save
Else
@book.bar -=1
@book.save
End
```

In the view
I have <%=button_to ‘add1’, increase_or_decrease_path(@book)%>
This adds one and removes one whenever all other users click on it…That is not what I want. Please could someone direct me here on what to do? I am really lost here.

Answer (score 2):

By your description, it sounds like you want to maintain the counts per user, not just by the book.

one possible solution is to create a join table:

```
class Book
has_many :user_votes

class UserVotes
belongs_to :books
belongs_to :users

class User
has_many :user_votes
```

The foo and bar columns would then be defined in the UserVotes table instead.

That gives you access to `@user.user_votes -> all votes by that user`
and `@book.user_votes -> all votes on that book`

you would probably want to query them on both axis:

```
class UserVotes
...
scope :for_user, ->(user_id) { where(user_id: user_id) }
scope :for_book, ->(book_id) { where(book_id: book_id) }
```

Comment: What about the part where the user can toggle between adding one and removing one, is it the scope aspect? thanks in advance.

Comment: The methods you described in your question would work, but they would need to operate on the user_vote instead.

Comment: I have added the line below to the increase_and_decrease_foo method since I have the table containing foo in a different table now: following your method.I think I have set the relationship rightly.


@book.user_vote.each do |bsv|

if bsv.foo == 0 etc...


My view is like this

<% book.user_vote.each do|bsv|%>

<%=bsv.user_vote%>

remember I set the user_vote to be 0 as defult value.

Everything runs fine in the console, but it doesn't show on the view.

Comment: This may help to throw more light too. I am using Book's controller for the methods.

Comment: I created a different controller for it and called it just as you directed here:https://gist.github.com/supersimple/f1eb967e712e56baeef771bc4d922426. but I get a synthax error on the console....dynamic constant assignment. Any idea how to resolve this please?